# Material design navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

So what I'm trying to do is to add a navigation drawer **within** a navigation drawer in a material design app. For reference you can look at the Piktures gallery app. When you click on the hamburger menu, it opens, and right next to the menu will appear an arrow. If you click on the arrow, yet another navigation drawer panel opens from the left which has the social network follow buttons. I just need a way to make another navigation drawer open from the same area. Do I add another fragment? Perhaps a fragment within the fragment? Please either give me a concept to read up on or simply a link to a tutorial. If you're feeling particularly generous, maybe you could even leave me the step by step in the answer. I am using Eclipse, not Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

**Mike Penz** has developed an awesome library to include a Navigation Drawer into your app with all the Google Material Design guidelines. You can find it on Github, [here](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer).